# I cannot save more than 50 data to the database at once. Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

What I want: When the application is first opened, I add the data I receive from the service to the list. I want to save the data I added to the list to my sqflite database with a for loop.

Problem: Data (266 units) is added to the list from the service without any problems. The first 50 data are added to the database without any problems. After 50 data, the application does not take any action.

My codes were working fine before, I didn't understand what was happening, so it started giving errors.

The method I call on the splash screen:

```
_getData() async {
    await Provider.of<FirestoreDataNotifier>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchRecommendedContentsOfTheWeek();

    Config.sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

Notifier method:

```
Future<void> fetchRecommendedContentsOfTheWeek() async {
    List<RecommendedVideoModel> _tempList = [];
    _isCompletely = false;
    try {
      Some transactions...

      await getAndAddData();

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      e.toString();
    }
  }
```

print('-> getAndAddData Successfully!'); It doesn't continue the line, it stays in the loop.

```
Future<void> getAndAddData() async {
    List<ContentModel> _list = [];
    _list = await FirestoreService().getAllData();

    for (var element in _list) {
      await AllContentDatabaseHelper.instance.add(
        ContentModel(
            title: element.title,
            thumbnailUrl: element.thumbnailUrl,
            content: element.content,
            id: element.id,
            categoryName: element.categoryName,
            categoryId: element.categoryId,
            estimatedTime: element.estimatedTime,
            publishedDate: element.publishedDate,
            videoUrl: element.videoUrl!.isEmpty ? ' ' : element.videoUrl),
      );
    }
    print('-> getAndAddData Successfully!');
    _list.clear();
    await getDataSize();
    _isCompletely = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

And add method:

```
Future<void> add(ContentModel contentModel) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    await db.insert(_tableName, contentModel.toMap());
    print('-> OK!');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a batch,

```
batch = db.batch();
batch.insert(_tableName, contentModel.toMap());
results = await batch.commit(noResult: true);
```

From this : https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

**UPDATE:**

Since, first answer's not working, try the raw approach, something like this:

```
  insertData(List< ContentModel> rows) async {
    final db = await database;
    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    rows.forEach((c) {
      if (buffer.isNotEmpty) {
        buffer.write(",\n");
      }
      buffer.write("(");
      buffer.write(c.id);
      buffer.write(", '");
      buffer.write(c.title);
      buffer.write("', '");
      buffer.write(c.thumbnailUrl);
      buffer.write("', '");
      buffer.write(c.content);
      buffer.write("', '");
      buffer.write(c.categoryName);
      buffer.write("', ");
      buffer.write(c.categoryId);
      buffer.write(", '");
      buffer.write(c.estimatedTime);
      buffer.write("', '");
      buffer.write(c.publishedDate);
      buffer.write("', '");
      buffer.write(c.videoUrl);
      buffer.write("'),");
    });
    var raw =
        await db.rawInsert("INSERT Into $_tableName (id,title, thumbnailUrl, content, categoryName, categoryId, estimatedTime, publishedDate,videoUrl)"
            " VALUES ${buffer.toString()}");
    return raw;
  }
```

To get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename' ('column1', 'column2', 'column3') VALUES
                ('data1', 'data2', 'data3'),
                ('data1', 'data2', 'data3'),
                ('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```

Comment: Hello, nothing has changed. Again only wrote 50 data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Output as: (1) near "te": syntax error

Comment: The error is 'videoUrl: element.videoUrl!.isEmpty ? I found that ' ' : element.videoUrl' is here. Some content urls are empty in the service. I'm checking here, but the blanks are causing problems during registration.